# Can not install WxPython with Python 2.7 on Windows 10

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I am new to Python, I want to use the Scyther tool on Windows 10, I downloaded python 2.7 (as requested by the Scyther tool), the problem is I can't install wxpyhton! I tried everything :( Please help.....

I tried many command lines to install WxPython but no use.
Some examples:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wxPython
ERROR: No matching distribution found for wxPython

Comment: ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 Complete output (33 lines):
    running install
    running build
    WARNING: Building this way assumes that all generated files have been
    generated already.  You can use
    --skip-build with the bdist_* or install commands to avoid this
    message and the wxWidgets and Phoenix build steps in the future.
    Running command: build
    Running command: build_wx
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Comment: Don't use any tool that binds you to a Python version that was EOL'd 2 years ago.